# Chrome - Close pdf opened tab keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

Ctrl+W is the shortcut for closing a tab in google chrome and if the tab opened has a pdf file then the keyboard shortcut doesnt work. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+W **doesn't close** tabs with **Flash video, too.** Try this:

1. Open in a new tab this:

   > http://www.youtube.com/embed/[YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID]
2. Click Play.
3. Press CTRL+W.

You will see that the tab will not close.

I think that your problem is similar with this...

Answer (score 0):

2 trolls Than a real answer

What is so hard with clicking x in the top

Get Firefox

but real answer is there is none yet I looked before. If you open in new window there is always cmd-q (Mac) alt-F4 (Windows)

Comment: 1) its not about it being hard to click x. Why are keyboard shortcuts there for applications if everything can be done using mouse. Its about flexibility and convenience for keyboard users.  2) Alt+f4 closes entire window and not tab.. thanks for a response though